# Converting this table of rgb values to hex color values?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

how would i convert this:

```
import json

import cv2 as cv2

import numpy as np


class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (np.int_, np.intc, np.intp, np.int8,
                            np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.uint8,
                            np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64)):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32,
                              np.float64)):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

jsonReturn = json.dumps(cv2.resize(Frame, self.Resolution, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST), cls=NumpyEncoder)
```

to all hex color values?

[image] (Note: There is `]]` and `[[` at some points)]

Comment: You want to convert a piece of Python code into hex colours?

Comment: nono, i want the list converted into hex colors

Comment: You want a picture of a list converted to hex??? What's the code for, please?

Answer (score 0):

my attempt:

input, `'test.png'`:

[image]

code :

```
import json

import cv2 as cv2

import numpy as np



Frame = cv2.imread('test.png')

print((Frame.shape[0],(Frame.shape[1])))

Resolution = (Frame.shape[0],Frame.shape[1])


def rgb_to_hex(i):
    """Return color as #rrggbb for the given color values."""
    return '#%02x' % (i)



class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
 
        if isinstance(obj, (np.int_, np.intc, np.intp, np.int8,
                            np.int16, np.int32, np.int64, np.uint8,
                            np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64)):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, (np.float_, np.float16, np.float32,
                              np.float64)):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, (np.ndarray,)):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


pippo = cv2.resize(Frame, Resolution, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST).astype('int')

# print(pippo, type(pippo))

rgb_to_hex_vectorized = np.vectorize(rgb_to_hex)

pippo = rgb_to_hex_vectorized(pippo)

# print(pippo, type(pippo))

jsonReturn = json.dumps(pippo, cls=NumpyEncoder) 

with open('saved.json', 'w') as fil:
     fil.write(jsonReturn)
```

output:
[image]